# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm using a reviews data and trying to apply classifier model and get prediction. Here is the code i'm trying.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Scraping reviews.csv')
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 8)
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.normal(0, 0.4, 8)
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(dataset)
#X_train_counts=X_train_counts.reshape(4,1)
X_train_counts.shape
[out] (2,2)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
#X_train_tf=X_train_tf.reshape(4,1)
X_train_tf.shape
[out] (2,2)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
#X_train_tfidf=X_train_tfidf.reshape(4,1)
X_train_tfidf.shape
[out] (2,2)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, X_train_counts)








 [out] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-494-7734b71b758f> in <module>
          1 from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
          2 
    ----> 3 clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, X_train_counts)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        613         self : object
        614         """
    --> 615         X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
        616         _, n_features = X.shape
        617         self.n_features_ = n_features
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in _check_X_y(self, X, y)
        478 
        479     def _check_X_y(self, X, y):
    --> 480         return self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr')
        481 
        482     def _update_class_log_prior(self, class_prior=None):
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
        430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
        431             else:
    --> 432                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
        433             out = X, y
        434 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
         70                           FutureWarning)
         71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
    ---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
         73     return inner_f
         74 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
        805                         ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
        806     else:
    --> 807         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        808         _assert_all_finite(y)
        809     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
         70                           FutureWarning)
         71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
    ---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
         73     return inner_f
         74 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
        843         return np.ravel(y)
        844 
    --> 845     raise ValueError(
        846         "y should be a 1d array, "
        847         "got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape))
    
    ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
    
    I tried reshaping X_train_counts, X_train_tf, X_train_tfidf but nothing is working. Please help me with this. Thanks.
```

Comment: you provide wrong parameters to `MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, X_train_counts)` [check documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html)

Comment: according to the error shown, you should reshape y not X.

Comment: you are giving X two times instead of y. You declare your y but never use it. The function fit expects (X,y) and  you are giving (X, and some other X)